# What is the difference between Intel TXT and TPM?

Tags: intel, tpm, trusted-computing

What is the difference between Intel TXT and TPM? What more Intel TXT has to offer as compared to TPM?
Basically, I wanted to know how TXT works? Any easy to follow literature for beginners will be highly appreciated!

Comment: What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: I wanted to know how TXT works? Any easy to follow literature for beginners will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Then first of all you should rephrase your question ;-)

Comment: Consider it as rephrased!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Scolytus is right but let me explain a bit more.

As he said, a TPM is a dependency of TXT but not the other way around. The TPM is where TXT will store the measurements - hash of components - of the platform. If TXT is not supported by a platform but a TPM is still present you still have all those features:

- Integrity measurement – securely measure the platform's components (hashes stored within the TPM)
- Authenticated boot – a process by which a platform's state (the sum of its components) is reliably measured and stored. SRTM - Static Root of Trust for Measurements
- Sealed Storage - encrypt data based on the current state of the platform or in other words, what has been measured (the PCR hash values stored in the TPM) - seal operation
- Attestation - securely report to other parties the state of the platform, e.g., quote operation aka Remote Attestation.

As such you could use trustedgrub (SRTM - Static Root of Trust for Measurements) but not tboot which implements a DRTM (Dynamic Root of Trust for Measurements) aka TXT.

About "how TXT works" see [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39329/how-does-the-tpm-perform-integrity-measurements-on-a-system) question.

Comment: Is my understanding correct that SRTM measures up-till PCR7 (before the OS is loaded) and DRTM measures OS and the application being launched over OS? 
Basically PCR0-PCR7 will be identical in SRTM and DRTM?

Comment: Well, that's not **how** TXT works, but if Geek is happy... ;-)

Comment: @Scolytus your comment is about the answer or my comment? :)

Comment: He's talking about my answer. Since "how txt works" has already been answered, I added a link to it. SRTM can measure up to PCR15 (but it depends on implementation - tpm aware OS, bootloader, etc). DRTM, does not measure the boot sequence so yes, PCRs are unchanged.

Comment: @Scolytus I'm not entirely sure the word 'implement' is correct as someone could understand that tboot is like TXT while it simply 'uses' DRTM (to provide secure boot). DRTM/LAte Launch implementations are Intel's TXT and AMD's SVM. What do you think?

Comment: @northox Hmmm... I'm not a native, so help me. Intel TXT itself is not an implementation of a DRTM. It needs software around it. It **needs** the *OS* and the *MLE* part, as described in the Software Development guide. Without an MLE you'll never have a DRTM. TBoot implements the OS and the MLE parts of the architecture. So I thought *require* is the wrong wording, since TBoot is vital in such a setup. One could also mention that there are other implementations as well.

Comment: In that sense, I agree. My comment was about the Root of Trust which is either provided by the CRTM: bios boot block (SRTM) or the SMX instructions + ACM module, etc (DRTM). I believe that's a confusing part for newcomers.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful :)
@Scolytus Could you look at this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705588/which-pcr-can-be-extended-by-our-own-code

Your help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It's like asking "*What's the difference between a car and an engine?*"

The TPM is a vital part of Intel TXT. Without it Intel TXT does not work.